# Datagridview Format Column Issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to format 2 columns in two different formats

first column 4 digit width, i need the output to be 123.4 when the user types in 1234.

i tried using

```
__dgw.Columns["column"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1";
```

but the output is 1,234.0  i dont want commas and just need 123.4 i tried d1 etc

is there such a thing as a masked column?

i also need a way a way to create another column with a mask of ##-##-##?

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend on using this type of behavior more frequently in the future, consider the following links for reference - particularly the last:

- [C# Datagridview MaskedTextBox Column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d51fd985-b13f-4cfc-8152-8bcea04bb8bf/c-datagridview-maskedtextbox-column?forum=winforms)
- [Datagridview cell specific custom mask](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a92df8b2-56ce-4658-a9ae-600ef82e4852/datagridview-cell-specific-custom-mask?forum=winformsdatacontrols)
- [DataGridViewColumn Hosting MaskedTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox)

If this is a one shot deal, perhaps less work would be the following:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "000.0";
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "00-00-00";

this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += this.DataGridView1_CellFormatting;

private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  int value = 0;

  if (e.Value != null && int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out value))
  {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
      // Must manually move decimal. Setting Format will not do this for you.
      e.Value = (decimal)value / 10;
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
      // Format won't affect e.Value of type string.
      e.Value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

This should provide the exact results desired while leaving the underlying value in tact.

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ User Input ║ Displayed ║ Actual Cell Value ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║    1234    ║   123.4   ║       1234        ║
║   123456   ║  12-34-56 ║      123456       ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

This also assumes you've limited the user to numeric entries of lengths 4 and 6 respectively, which can be done as follows:

```
this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += this.DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(AllowNumericOnly);
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
  {
    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
      tb.Tag = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 ? 4 : 6;
      tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.AllowNumericOnly);
    }
  }
}

private void AllowNumericOnly(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  var control = sender as Control;
  int length = (int)control.Tag;

  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || control.Text.Length >= length))
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```